# Pie Chart not getting displayed with dynamic data. I am using Highchart

Tags: javascript, angular, api, highcharts, angular10

This is where I am calling API

```
var chart_data = []
.
.
  success: (data) => 
  {
    var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    if (json.AssessorCertificationDetailedData.StatusId == "1"){
      this.userData = json.AssessorCertificationDetailedData.StatewiseAssessorData
      for(var i in this.userData)
      {
        var item = this.userData[i];
        chart_data.push([
          item.StateName,
          item.StateId
        ])
       
      }
    }
  },
  error: function (err) {
    console.log('error:' + err);
  },
});
```

This is how I am passing data into highchart series.

```
series: [
  {
      data: 
        chart_data
  }
]
```

Pie chart is not getting displayed. I am unable to figure out what is the mistake in my data format.

Comment: Create a stackblitz to reproduce the same.

Comment: Where are you assigning chart_data to highchart ? Assign inside success callback

Comment: I would be nice if you could create a simple demo with that issue. There are a lot of things which we don't know, like where do you assign the data, what format is that data, which might have an impact on the final result. You might start with this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line